# Show Pdf File Options

Tags: blackberry

How to show pdf file in BlackBerry application.I am trying to showing pdf file in browserField but it is

showing error "Load page error "  I have tried a lot of but did't get any soluation.Please  help I am stuck

from long time

This is my pdf url:

http://iphone.imagescreations.eu/apps/salmson/fichiers/AQUASON-AL-PAP_NT_ENG_50Hz.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot show the pdf in blackberry browser. Because, Blackberry does not provide api for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if there is no way and just found this library :

[PDF Renderer for BlackBerry.](http://pdfrend4bb.codeplex.com/)

check if that is what you are looking for or not.